# Keep PingFederate IDP session alive from SP

Tags: session, keep-alive, pingfederate

We're implementing a web SSO solution using PingFederate, with a 3rd party product that includes SAML2 out of the box.

However we're trying to work through the question of how to stop the IDP session timing out if the user is still actively using the SP.

The 3rd party product supports requesting an empty resource on the IDP side, with the intention that this URL would result in the IDP session being extended.

I can't see anything in PingFederate that supports anything like this. Does anybody know how this is generally resolved? Is there a way to extend the PingFederate session e.g. API call, HTTP POST to an endpoint, whatever?

Or does the SP need to construct a new authenticate request? If so, does this result in a new SAML response / token being issued with a new `NotOnOrAfter` date?

Comment: Why do you need to keep your IdP session alive? The SP session should be entirely self-contained.

Comment: We're doing this to enable single sign on. You go to one application, get prompted to log in, use that application for a while and then jump to another application where you are seamlessly signed in. If you don't keep the IDP session alive, even though you were actively using the first SP, you'll get prompted to log in again when jumping to the second SP if the IDP session has expired.

Comment: Just use a stateless authentication adapter, like IWA, if this is what you need... What you're trying to do here isn't supported by SAML... It's supported by traditional WAM, like, as Ian noted, PingAccess. I suppose you could use OAuth or OIDC as well.

Comment: Yeah I think I'd like to explore the PingAccess option - need to explore further with our integration vendor, who seem to think it's not possible in a SAML scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't a use case that SAML 2.0 covers and any solution that fits within the SAML 2.0 spec will probably be custom to an individual product. Additionally, is no way to have the SP extend the session at PingFed (IDP) except to do another round-trip for SSO.

Typically customers handle this by making the session at the IDP long-lived so that user's are not prompted to login again when switching between SPs.

If you control both the IDP and the SP, then I'd recommend looking at using PingAccess in conjunction with PingFederate. You can still Federate into the application via PingFed but PingAccess will allow you to manage the sessions across applications.

Comment: Thanks @Ian. I considered making the IDP session long lived but then it requires an explicit logout to stop users getting access, because whenever an SP times out, next time the user accesses the site the SP will bounce the user over to the IDP, PingFederate will say "all good, you can go in" and they're back in without authentication. In other words the IDP session will overrule everything else from a security point of view. (Unless I've misunderstood how that works?)

Comment: Yes we control IDP and SP (SP only in the sense we deploy a 3rd party app) so we have PingAccess, but I was told by our implementation vendor that if we use the web browser SSO profile then PingAccess has no real role to play. Originally I'd thought we could use OpenID Connect between client and PA and then whatever standard (SAML, OAuth, OpenToken, whatever) between PF and the back end systems but I've been told it's not how it works. Can you elaborate on how we use PA as the gateway / session manager but still use SAML to federate to back end systems?

Comment: Why use SAML to backends? Just use SAML to PF as SP from other partners, then front-end your backend apps with PingAccess. No SAML needed to backend apps. Throw the attributes in the headers for the apps to consume, and you're done. There's a 4-day PingAccess training coming up in November, probably would make sense for you to attend!
https://4.pingidentity.com/15-11-10-BurlingtonPingAccessRegistration.html

Comment: Hi @Andrew, unfortunately the app in question is a vendor product which supports SAML out of the box but nothing else. We're trying to work within their constraints as much as possible and limit any enhancements as they can be expensive. A wholesale change to OAuth or OIDC or a custom header approach would be a large architectural change for them and is beyond our budget to do. Ping training would be great except I doubt I'll get approval for international flights and accommodation! :)

Comment: If the application supports SAML 2.0 OOTB, the I imagine it supports SSO integration via standard HTTP headers (even SiteMinder ones)? PA can set any header value so if the app can be integrated with SM that way there's no app changes required to work with PA.

Comment: Unfortunately no, SAML is all they support.

Comment: @Ian, I've been thinking on this more and am thinking the best way to solve this might be through a "bridge" that acts as a SAML IDP but instead of prompting the user to log in when it receives a SAML AuthnRequest it just checks the PA credentials in the HTTP headers, then responds with the AuthnResponse as normal. The "bridge" web page would be a PA-protected resource, so if they hit the page without a PA session then PA, not PF, would prompt them to login. What do you think? Is there anything in PF which would allow me (e.g. authentication selectors) without writing an IDP from scratch?

Comment: It took a while to get the model I was originally after but having PingAccess and PingFederate share an IDP adapter was the key to the bridge between PA & PF, and making PingAccess treat even the SAML application as protected was the key to having a common web session across all apps. I plan to set the PA max web session length to be a few minutes short of the IDP idle session, so PA will reauthenticate before the IDP session times out, and this will result in the IDP session being extended. I need to figure out how this will work with APIs, though... :(

Comment: Can't this use case be catered by using 'isPassive' field of authnrequest as mentioned here? https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/isPassive